# What is the difference between "la semana siguiente" and "a la semana siguiente"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, selección-de-palabras, preposiciones, diferencias-entre-palabras

I see both of these variations from time to time and, thus far, have not recognized a pattern that helps me to decide when to use which.  Nor have I found anything that dictates whether or not one form is correct and the other is not.  Here are some examples I found:

### la semana siguiente

[**"Puede ser el peor quarterback de la liga una semana y jugar como John Elway la semana siguiente".**](https://www.primeroydiez.com/2019/10/01/analisis-de-la-semana-4-de-la-nfl-temporada-2019/)
*"He can be the worst quarterback in the league one week and play like John Elway the following week."*

[**"... se celebrarán la semana siguiente".**](https://www.elcomercio.es/asturias/oriente/festival-avellana-contara-20190925001548-ntvo.html)
*... will be held the following week."*

[**"... puede ser indicativo de lo que pueda pasar la semana siguiente, ..."**](https://lta.reuters.com/articulo/economia-global-semana-idLTAKCN1VR1AW)
*"... may be indicative of what may happen the following week, ..."*

### a la semana siguiente

[**"Pero a la semana siguiente su estado físico fue empeorando."**](https://www.abc.es/espana/madrid/abci-familia-mujer-amputaron-pierna-negligencia-medica-cobrara-150000-euros-201909190035_noticia.html)
*"But the following week his physical condition was getting worse."*

[**"... el Palacio respondió a la semana siguiente ..."**](https://www.ultimahora.es/noticias/sociedad/2019/09/18/1107385/reina-isabel-devuelve-mono-juguete-perdido-nina-australiana.html)
*"... the Palace responded the following week ..."*

[**"... les sometieron a un examen a los 5 minutos, y otro a la semana siguiente".**](https://computerhoy.com/noticias/life/sencillo-truco-memorizar-cualquier-cosa-ciencia-466377)
*"... they underwent an exam after 5 minutes, and another one the following week."*

I don't see any real difference between these two sets of examples.  However, after looking at a few of these, it seems possible that the inclusion of "a" before a phrase like "la semana siguiente" may indicate a greater fluidity of time.  In other words, the difference between simply saying "next week" (la semana siguiente) and "*by* next week" (a la semana siguiente).  In fact, I would think that if I needed to specify "by next week," I would need to use "a la semana siguiente."  Correct?

Can anyone comment on this or add citations from reputable sources that address this difference?  Are there any instances in which you have to use one or the other or is it optional?  Does one variation sound more natural to you?

---

**¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "la semana siguiente" and "a la semana siguiente"?**

Veo ambas frases de vez en cuando y, hasta ahora, no he reconocido un patrón que me ayuda decidir cuando cada una ser utilizada.  Ni he encontrado nada que dice que una forma es la correcta.  Aquí están algunos ejemplos que encontré:

[Véanse arriba.]

No veo ninguna diferencia real entre estos dos conjuntos de ejemplos.  Sin embargo, despúes de ver algunas de estas, parece posible que la inclusión de "a" antes de una frase como "la semana siguiente" puede indicar una mayor fluidez en tiempo.  En otras palabras, la diferencia entre simplemente decir "next week" (la semana siguiente) y "*by* next week" (a la semana siguiente).  De hecho, pensaría que si tuviese que especificar "by next week," necesitaría usar "a la semana siguiente"?  ¿Correcto?

¿Alguien puede comentar sobre esto o añadir citas de fuentes confiables que abordan esta diferencia?  ¿Hay situaciones en que tienes que usar una o la otra?  O, ¿es opcional?  ¿Te suena una más natural?

Comment: ... and then there's *la siguiente semana*....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

. El uso de la preposición "***a***"  —en 'a la* semana siguiente"— es necesario cuando se quiere consignar la ligazón temporal de lo que ocurre antes y después en la oración. Sirve para hacer una referencia de tiempo relativa**. Vinculándo una segunda cosa con el momento específico al que la frase alude.

Para comprenderlo mejor a mi me sirvió hacer ejemplos en otras unidades de tiempo (ya que el sentido se aplica igualmente con cualquiera: al minuto, a la *hora*, al *año* siguiente, etc)

> *Ingresó al partido cuando el marcador ponía en peligro la clasificación misma del equipo, a la media hora siguiente, la magia de su juego y sus goles lo habían cambiado todo.*
>
> *El bebé se removía inquieto y fastidiado, al minuto siguiente estaba plácidamente dormido.*
>
> *Dijo que se trataría la herida con unas hierbas que se abuelo conocía. A la semana siguiente, estaba increíblemente sano.*

Como puede verse en las oraciones arriba, usando la *a* como conector en el salto temporal, se consigue mostrar que la acción o el hecho subordinado está claramente  vinculado al momento referido con anterioridad

> Este párrafo [de un libro](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=TWs04OJsyY0C&pg=PA45&dq=a%20la%20semana%20siguirente&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYgfOX2orlAhXOIbkGHc1ZAxoQ6AEIRzAD#v=onepage&q&f=false) muestra el mecanismo de ambos usos y quizás haga explícito el patrón: 
>   [image: ejemplo doble]
>
> ***la semana próxima*** ... es el plazo que alguien usa para comprometerse a hacer algo; la narración continúa refiriendo que ***a la semana siguiente*** [desde ese momento de la promesa] *se repite la misma película* [todo sigue igual]

Diría que aunque en algunos casos no se necesite usarla (como en el ejemplo tuyo del quarterback) **en general la diferencia de emplear la preposición, es esa capacidad de referencia relativa** que la construcción aporta.

**Addendum**: 
Soy un hablante nativo del idioma español por lo que la explicación dada hasta aquí fue sólo producto de la observación de los usos sobre los que preguntabas. Ahora. como releo y veo tu pedido de fuentes reputadas, adjunto el siguiente párrafo, —que ratifica lo que expresé— dentro de un trabajo académico de [María Ángeles Sastre Ruano](https://hispanismo.cervantes.es/hispanistas/222194/sastre-ruano-maria-angeles), profesora de la Universidad de Valladolid, titulado "*[Para hablar de un momento posterior a otro. La referencia al futuro](https://cvc.cervantes.es/ensenanza/biblioteca_ele/asele/pdf/07/07_0409.pdf)*"

> Cuando el hablante se refiere a momentos pasados, pero posteriores al punto de referencia y anteriores al punto presente del hablante, se utilizan las expresiones: a) cantidad de tiempo (9 meses, 10 días) + *después*; b) *al cabo de* + cantidad de tiempo; c) *al / a la(s) / a los *mes /día/año/semana/hora...*
>
> *Envié el cuento no sin cierta timidez y **veinte días después** / **a los veinte días** / **al cabo de veinte días** me comunicaron que había recibido el premio*

[image: referencia a momentos pasados pero posteriores al punto de referencia]

Answer (score 2):

As you have already guessed, in phrases like *a la semana siguiente* the preposition *a* suggests continuity or the passage of time, while the same phrase without the preposition simply sets up a new timeframe. The difference is subtle and often the two versions of the phrase are interchangeable.

Of the three examples you gave without *a*, one could have the preposition:

> *"Puede ser el peor quarterback de la liga una semana y jugar como John Elway (a) la semana siguiente".*

With *a*, this would emphasize the paradoxical nature of this player, since the implied continuity is at odds with the radically different performance from one week to the next.

The other two examples without *a* would sound odd if you added it, because there's no clear continuity there.

Regarding the three following examples, which do include the preposition, I'd say all three could do without it, with no major change in meaning. They do sound better (more natural) as they are, especially the first and maybe the third, since they suggest an enduring condition (a medical condition under observation). The second one,

> *"... el Palacio respondió (a) la semana siguiente ..."*

could do without the *a*, but I guess most speakers would keep it too, because it again suggests continuity: in this case, continuity of expectation for a reply.

Comment: I know you aren't overly concerned about who gets the green check mark, but I feel compelled to at least thank you for contributing to this thread with an answer.  Yours is quite good, but in terms of effort and sources cited, I'm going to award this one to user2325442.  (Plus, he has fewer rep points.)  Again, thank you for your efforts here.